# Failed to initialise the LWJGL display

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick, eclipse

I added the fix of adding this line "Dorg.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL=true" to vm arguments, updated my drivers but nothing is working......my error message still remain same has shown in the image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error message is commonly caused by outdated video card drivers. To fix this, make sure you're using the latest version of LWJGL and have the latest version of your graphics card's video drivers installed.

Answer (score 0):

First see [Thomas's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/129288/2624) about upgrading your drivers, but there are also [known issues with Java 64bit and OpenGL on Windows](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2487913-windows-10-need-help-solved) as well as [known compatibility with EOL Intel Graphics chips](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/issues/119#issuecomment-262090230). You haven't shown your configuration so we don't know what the issue is.

The solution for the first problem is to run the 32-bit version of Java, the solution for the second is an unsupported patch of the Intel HD Graphics driver. Usual caveats about installing drivers by some guy on the internet apply.